# Creating new variable in R: a proportion of 2 existing variables

Tags: r

I would like to analyse the proportion of infected bees(DWV/TOTAL) in function of time (DAY_SINCE_TREATMENT), but how do I create a new variable: the proportion of infected bees (DWV/TOTAL)? 
The dataset looks like this:

```
      COLONY DAY_SINCE_TREATMENT CTRL DWV TOTAL  
    1      A                  11    0   1     1  
    2      A                  13    4   3     7  
    3      A                  15   17   8    25  
    4      A                  17    3   0     3  
    5      A                  18    7   1     8  
    6      A                  19    6   1     7
```

Comment: Try `DF1$PROP <- DF1$DWW/DF1$TOTAL`

Answer (score 0):

We can create the PROP variable by

```
DF1$PROP <- DF1$DWW/DF1$TOTAL
```